# Draggable Regions in Oracle's APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to move regions on the client side? I am not speaking in terms of the Page Designer/Grid Layout?

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported "out of the box" in APEX, but since APEX uses jQuery it is easy to achieve using the [jQuery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) functionality.  I have set up an example you can see [here on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=35008:9).  This is based on the Universal Theme.

Here are some screenshots showing the page as loaded and after I dragged the region down to the bottom right:

[image: Before dragging]

[image: After dragging]
What I did was:

1. Create a "container" static content region with template "Blank with attributes" and static ID "container".  This defines the area within which the main region can be dragged.  I found that without this it could be dragged from side to side OK, but if dragged downwards it got clipped.
2. Create the draggable region as a "normal" APEX region with static ID "dept-report-rgn": I went for a classic report based on the DEPT table. I made it a sub-region of the container region, and assigned these CSS classes in the region "CSS Classes" property (under "Appearance"): `ui-widget-content draggable-region`.  The class `ui-widget-content` is required by jQuery, and `draggable-region` is my own invention.
3. In page property "Javascript - Execute when page loads" I added the following code:

   `$( function() { $( ".draggable-region" ).draggable(); } );`

   This applies the jQuery `draggable` functionality to **any** element with the class "draggable-region".  I could instead have targeted my specific region by selecting "#dept-report-rgn" instead of the class.
4. In page property "CSS - Inline" I added the following:

   `#container .container {height: 600px}`

   `#dept-report-rgn { width: 300px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em; }`

The first line ensures that there is some vertical space within which the draggable region can move, the second specifies the size of the draggable region itself.

This may not quite what you need, but it hopefully shows you a way forward.  You may also want to look at the jQuery [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) components (for example).